# AVFoundation not getting sample buffer

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation

I'm trying to get an image from a sample buffer, but the method isn't even firing. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {


NSLog(@"Sample Buffered");
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
IOSurfaceRef surface = CVPixelBufferGetIOSurface(imageBuffer);
CIImage* ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithIOSurface:surface];
}
```

Comment: How did you set whatever object this code is in as a delegate?

Comment: How does your sample buffer setup looks like? Should look something like the following:
`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [self.session addOutput:output];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];`

Comment: @DanielAlbertini - Thank you. I tried that and it fired properly.

Comment: @DanielAlbertini - When I try to access the image I get this error -    CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT
clSetKernelArg() source image failed:            Does this have to do with the image buffer? Or am I just accessing it wrong

Comment: It is important that you lock and unlock your imageBuffer. ex. `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);` and `CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);`

Comment: @DanielAlbertini - Do I do that in -captureOutput?

Comment: yes you should lock ist before you use the image buffer and unlock it after you created your CIImage

Comment: @DanielAlbertini - I'm still getting that error. This is my code as of right now                `CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    
    IOSurfaceRef surface = CVPixelBufferGetIOSurface(imageBuffer);
    
    CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithIOSurface:surface];
    
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);`

Comment: I don't know the CVPixelBufferGetIOSurface method and I don't know what you try to accomblish with this method but if you are just trying to create an CIImage from your buffer you can do so with the following CIImage constructor
CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];

Comment: @DanielAlbertini - I am programming this for OS X, so I cannot use that method.

Comment: @DanielAlbertini - My intent is to get the current frame as an NSImage and then try to retrieve color information about each pixel after converting the NSImage into and NSBitmapImageRep.

Comment: Sorry overlooked the osx tag, on the Mac you should use the following CIImage constructor: `- (id)initWithCVImageBuffer:(CVImageBufferRef)imageBuffer`.

Comment: Do I use that as an entirely new method?

Comment: Nevermind. I got it to work. Just one more question. I can see the image loading properly in the console, however when I loaded up my project this morning the previewLayer was no longer working. After some further investigating I found that there was another project I found that seemed to have the same classes, and when an edit was made to one, it was made to the other. I was able to get the original project loaded again but the preview is blank. If i showed you what my code is do you think you'd be able to identify an obvious issue if one exists?